# Free and legal camping sites in Czechia

Tags: camping, czech-republic

In Poland, there is a bunch of places where you can camp for free and legal, see [this map](https://www.bdl.lasy.gov.pl/portal/mapy?t=0&ll=19.624436,51.992766&scale=4622324&map=8,1.0&layers=26,27,28,29,30,32,33,34,35,37,38,39,40,42,43,45,46,47,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,62,63,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72&basemap=2&extwms=&hist=).

I'm looking for a similar map of sites for Czechia.

Comment: Have you checked the general rules for the country? In some countries free camping is almost always legal, in other countries almost never.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.